# Clearing cookie in web socket handler.

Tags: tornado

Within Tornado's `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` `get_secure_cookie()` works however the `clear_cookie()` function raises the following exception:

```
    raise RuntimeError("Method not supported for Web Sockets")
RuntimeError: Method not supported for Web Sockets
```

Pretty obvious by the description there that it's not supported. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported because once the connection is established, websockets are no longer HTTP and cannot send HTTP headers like `Set-Cookie`. You'll have to send a message which your javascript can handle by changing the cookie (either setting it directly if it is script-accessible, or making a separate HTTP requests if it is HTTP-only).